# How can I share (windows network shared drive) a virtual disk drive in C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, driver, disk, file-sharing

I have succesfully compiled the 'file device driver' found here (filedisk) :
https://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/

Unfortunately, when I try to 'share' the new created device, the following message appears:

> An error occurred while sharing .The device or directory does not
>   exist. The shared resource was not created

To summarize, here is the method used to mount file as drive:

```
int FileDiskMount(...)
...
DefineDosDevice(DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH,"T:","\Device\FileDisk\FileDisk0")
...
Device = CreateFile("\\.\T:",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,NULL);

DeviceIoControl(Device,IOCTL_FILE_DISK_OPEN_FILE,OpenFileInformation,sizeof(OPEN_FILE_INFORMATION) + OpenFileInformation->FileNameLength - 1,
  NULL,0,&BytesReturned,NULL))
```

*where OpenFileInformation->FileName = "\??\d:\fd.img"*

Do you know what's wrong ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do that in pure *standard*  C++11. You need some operating system specific library. Then you should tag your question as Windows specific. See also [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: When I talk about pure, it meens without any third party library or any other language (java, .net, ...). As 'Windows ' is mentioned in my question, I was thinking no such a doubt could be raised. I was wrong :-(. Thanks.

Comment: \\\\.\\T:    backslash is an escape character

Comment: In source code I have provided, all string are copied directly from debugger. So, you should 'double' all the backslash read in strings. Moreover, even if I use "\\\\.\\" or "\\\\?\\" in OpenFileInformation->FileName, it doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, thanks.